I dont understand how this C++ code does what it does?
int sumEvenDigits(const std::string cardNumber){

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = cardNumber.size() - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2){
        sum = sum + getDigit((cardNumber[i] - 48) * 2);

    }

    return sum;
}

In this C++ code, which i wrote by following a tutorial, however I don't get everything he's explaining. Like why does he minus the size of the cardNumber variable with two, like what is the point of turning 16 to 14? And why does he minus cardNumber[i] with 48?
I went over the video multiple times, however I don't get it.
Here is the whole code:
#include <iostream> 

int getDigit(const int number);

int sumEvenDigits(const std::string cardNumber);

int sumOddDigits(const std::string cardNumber);

int main(){

    std::string cardNumber;
    int result = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter your Credit Card: ";
    std::cin >> cardNumber;

    std::cout << cardNumber.size();

    result = sumEvenDigits(cardNumber) + sumOddDigits(cardNumber);

    if (result % 10 == 0){
        std::cout << "Card is valid!";
    } else{
        std::cout << "Card is invalid!";
    }

    return 0;
}

int getDigit(const int number){

    return number % 10 + (number / 10 % 10);
}

int sumEvenDigits(const std::string cardNumber){

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = cardNumber.size() - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2){
        sum = sum + getDigit((cardNumber[i] - 48) * 2);

    }

    return sum;
}

int sumOddDigits(const std::string cardNumber){

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = cardNumber.size() - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 2){
        sum = sum + cardNumber[i] - 48;

    }

    return sum;
}

And what happens in the code is we use the Luhn algorithm to check if a credit card is valid.
I'm a beginner btw, and thanks in advance.

cardNumber[i] is a character reprsented by an ASCII value. 48 is the ASCII value of '0', and therefore cardNumber[i] - 48 converts a character to its numeric value (assuming it is 0-9). For readability is it more common to write it as cardNumber[i] - '0'.

@Fluid It is just a bad code.:)

This is an odd way to implement the Luhn algorithm... It seems excessively complicated when comparing it to the algorithm on Wikipedia. For example, it'd probably make more sense to represent the number as an array of ints instead of a string, the string representation seems to be where a lot of your confusion comes from (take, for example, @wohlstad's point of cardNumber[i] - 48 being an ASCII conversion). If your goal is to learn, it might be worth a shot to try to implement it yourself from scratch.

The Internet is a bad place to learn to code. Unless you already have a good grasp on the fundamentals, it can be very hard to tell the material posted by a good programmer worth listening to from a bad or negligent programmer who's just in it for the ad revenue or to earn their Dunning-Kruger merit badge.

"I dont understand how this C++ code does what it does?... is not a good question title. How are future readers/askers supposed to get an idea about the question from this title. Also see Please explain what this code is doing (someChar - 48)

@Fluid This for loop for(int i = cardNumber.size() - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2){ starts its iterations from the first  digit in an even position (position 2) starting from the right side of the number stored in the string. That is according to the code the second digit from the right side of the number is stored in an even position. Subtracting 2 you will get a second digit in the position 4 starting from the right side of the number.

"And why does he minus cardNumber[i] with 48?" -- Because he prefers to use magic numbers instead of writing easy-to-read code. Which, by the way, is not a trait I would look for in a tutor...

To answer your questions:

@wohlstad explained the cardNumber[i] - 48 part well, it's an ascii conversion. The best way to do this is to use cardNumber[i] - '0', because it is more readable and supports other encodings (in programming, the 48 here is what is known as a "magic number", a number that exists without explanation which the code doesn't work without- this is considered bad practice). With that said, this implementation does generally work. The reasoning is, if you look at an ascii table, you'll see that the number 0 as a string is represented as 48 in ASCII. So, take '7' for example as a string. In ascii, 7 is 55. If you subtract 48 from that, you get 7 as an int.
In your sumEvenDigits() function, he subtracts 2 from the length. This is correct, and actually probably the best way to do it. If you look at the algorithim on Wikipedia, you'll see that you want to subtract the check digit. This accounts for subtracting 1 from the length. In this case, 2 is subtracted from the length because you want to check the even digits, and the first digit is odd, so you're ignoring that. If you look at the sumOddDigits() function, you'll see that 1 is subtracted from the length to also account for subtracting the check digit.


The code isn't getting an int from a string; it's getting digits. stoi() is not the right approach. And don't fall into ASCIIism: cardNumber[i] - '0' is the right way to do that conversion; it works for all character encodings, not just ASCII.
